# Firefox: Break on DOM property change

Tags: firefox, breakpoints

[Firebug for Firefox had Breakpoints on DOM (HTML) Mutation Events](https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html). [Firebug was merged into Firefox developer console](https://getfirebug.com/). I don't find the feature in the Firefox developer console, can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Found this:

"You set a DOM Mutation Breakpoint in the Page Inspector. Navigate to the DOM node in which you are interested and use the context menu to set the breakpoint."

"
Attribute Modification

Execution pauses when any of the elements' attributes are modified.
"

from
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Break_on_DOM_mutation